# git-filter-branch vs. rebase + reset --hard + push --force

Tags: git, version-control, git-rewrite-history

I have included a file in a commit that had my password on it, I pushed it, and later on realized the mistake I made.

I understand [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) (or [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)) helps cleaning up the history, however, how is that different from doing a...

1. `rebase -i` - moving the commit to the tip, then
2. `reset --hard [previous_commit]` - to apply this to the repo, then
3. `push --force`

Upon visualizing the results of the above steps in [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), I don't see the previous commit (and its contents), but I can imagine it may appear in history for others who already pulled the repo with the faulty commit, or even for new clones.

So what's basically the difference compared to [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)? Am I comparing apples to oranges?

**EDIT**: Looks like you can do steps 1 & 2 above in one go using `rebase -i --autosquash [commit_hash]`.

Comment: Last I checked, there was no such thing as `git reverse --hard`... Did you mean `git reset --hard`?

Comment: "but I can imagine it may appear in history for others who already pulled the repo with the faulty commit"  - yep.   "or even for new clones" -- nope. Not unless there's some other referenced history including that commit.

Comment: @twalberg Corrected, thanks!

Comment: @jthill What if I asked those who pulled already to `pull --force`? that would get rid of the commit I removed, right? Would it not be the same for git-filter-branch?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "get rid of".  The content isn't actually gone from any particular repository until a garbage collect cleans it out, and that won't by default actually delete any object that's been referenceable within the last month.  `git pull --force` will overwrite any remote-tracking-branch references for that particular remote but no others -- no tags, no local branches, no remote-tracking branches for other remotes.  `git filter-branch` just renames the original references; the old history isn't gone, just stashed out of the way until you clean it out yourself.

Comment: @jthill might be a good one for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use both methods to fix your issue. I would recommend `git rebase` because you have better control about what exactly you want the final commits to look like.

`git filter-branch` is much more suited to make changes to many commits, not just one.

Comment: They have to rebase their local branches against the new ones and manually drop the old commits. There are instructions on how to do that. That's the problem when rewriting history.